# How to find parameters $\theta_{12}, \theta_{13} $ and $ \theta_{23} $ for the lepton mixing matrix?

Tags: neutrinos, beyond-the-standard-model

I am currently studying neutrino physics and read that the PMNS matrix can be expressed through $9$ real parameters. I especially see parameters such as $\sin\theta_{12}$ popping up though, and I don't understand how you get from the PMNS matrix to these random parameters which I assume are part of the $9$ the PMNS matrix can be expressed in terms of?

Comment: [More on the PMNS matrix](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bneutrinos%5D+pmns+is%3Aq).

Answer (score 1):

Let's first understand why there are so few mixing angles. As Wikipedia explains [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontecorvo%E2%80%93Maki%E2%80%93Nakagawa%E2%80%93Sakata_matrix#Parameterization), the nine DOFs of a unitary matrix aren't all realized as mixing angles. There are six leptons, so the phases of five relative to the sixth account for five of the nine DOFs, all of which can be removed with a suitable coordinate choice. (This assumes Majorana neutrinos; Dirac neutrinos would add two mixing angles.) A fourth, $\delta_{\operatorname{CP}}$, quantifies CP violation; again, a suitable coordinate choice separates out the other three DOFs as mixing angles. In any case, it's small enough some pedagogical texts initially don't discuss it.

We could just as easily use different parameters, of course. So your question really has two aspects: (i) how do we measure the matrix's degrees of freedom in whichever parameters are most empirically convenient, and (ii) how do we restate that in terms of $\theta_{ij},\,\delta_{\operatorname{CP}}$? For (i), look up how we measure transition amplitudes, and for (ii), look up different ways to describe rotations in $3$ dimensions. Both are discussed briefly in the above link, albeit not in that order.

Comment: Okay thanks - I have looked into the resources provided. I have my own form of the PMNS matrix and then the form given in the wikipedia page, but how do I actually extract $sin(\theta_{23})$ for example? All the terms in the PMNS matrix are a product of other variables - is it possible to isolate the $sin(\theta_{23})$ term?